# Differentiating between left and right mouse clicks in QTableView

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtableview

I have a QTableView, in which both left and right mouse clicks result in some action.

The right click should launch a context menu, and the left should open another process.

I use the following connects for this purpose in my QMainWindow:

```cpp
connect(Table , SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested( const QPoint& ) ),this, SLOT( tableContextMenu( const QPoint& ) ) );
 connect(Table , SIGNAL (clicked ( const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(test()));
```

The Problem is fairly simple to see. Since I use `clicked()` signal to capture the left click — the right click is captured too. So, if I click on the right click button, **along with the context menu**, the **action reserved for the left click occurs as well**.

How do I avoid this?

```cpp
Table = new QTableView(this);
TableLayout *t = new TableLayout();
Table->setModel(t);
Table->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(Table , SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested( const QPoint& ) ),this, SLOT( tableContextMenu( const QPoint& ) ) );
```

This is how I do it for the right click context menu, and all are defined in `P14MainWindow` constructor, which is an object of `QMainWindow`.

Now where exactly should I reimplement `MouseReleaseEvent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To launch a context menu reimplement `QTableView::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* e)`, and  similarly reimplement `QTableView::mouse...Event(QMouseEvent* event)` to catch mouse events.

Then use `QTableView::indexAt(const QPoint& pos) const` to return the model index at the click site.

Here is an example of the left click handling:

```
void Table::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QTableView::mouseReleaseEvent( event );

    if ( event->button == Qt::LeftButton ) {
        test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`QGuiApplication::mouseButtons`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#mouseButtons) in a slot connected to the [`QAbstractItemView::clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget tableWidget;
    QMenu rightButtonMenu;
    QMenu leftButtonMenu;
    QAction leftAction("Left Button");
    QAction rightAction("Right Button");

    tableWidget.setColumnCount(5);
    tableWidget.setRowCount(5);

    rightButtonMenu.addAction(&rightAction);
    leftButtonMenu.addAction(&leftAction);
    rightButtonMenu.setStyleSheet("background: white; color: black;");
    leftButtonMenu.setStyleSheet("background: black; color: white;");

    QObject::connect(&tableWidget, &QAbstractItemView::pressed, [&rightButtonMenu, &leftButtonMenu](const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        switch(QApplication::mouseButtons())
        {
            case Qt::RightButton:
                rightButtonMenu.exec(QCursor::pos());
                break;
            case Qt::LeftButton:
                leftButtonMenu.exec(QCursor::pos());
                break;
        }
    });

    tableWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Note: This only works when an item is clicked. You could also apply it for the header views (e.g, [`QTableView::horizontalHeader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader)), since [QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html) inherits QAbstractItemView.